# Bring freshly updated content to web site

Tags: rss, syndication

What technology can be used on my website to bring in daily fresh updated content, like News RSS feed from a famous news website,... etc?

Comment: I dont think the c# .net and asp.net tags bear any relevance on content.  they might change how you implement it but ultimately the question is about features to be added not how to code them.

Comment: please can u recommend other tags i can put ,,, to get an answer to my question...

Comment: i need more technologies in addition to RSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Update - General answer]**

As you already mention, RSS feeds are your best way to get updated news. They are easily consumable and provide a standard interface for article based data. For example CNN has their top storries at http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss. When browsing news sites with Firefox it will display a RSS icon in the addressbar if the site has RSS feeds, which makes it easier to discover feeds.

---

Since you tag this as C# and ASP.Net I will answer it in terms of coding.

Many news sites offer RSS feeds and these can be consumed with the [SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) class introduced in .Net 3.5. The `SyndicationFeed` class supports both Atom 1.0 and RSS 2.0.

The most important part when consuming feeds in my opinion is to cache them, so that you don't download the feed for every hit on your web page. Where you get your feed from depends on what topics you want and where in the world you are located.

Here's a short example.

```
// Check cache for data
IEnumerable<SyndicationItem> items = Cache["NewsFeed"] as IEnumerable<SyndicationItem>;
if (items == null)
{
    // Not in cache, go get it!
    try
    {
        SyndicationFeed news = SyndicationFeed.Load(XmlReader.Create("http://www.news.corp/feed.xml"));
        items = news.Items;
    }
    catch
    {
        items = new List<SyndicationItem>();
    }
    // Add the items to the cache
    Cache.Insert("NewsFeed", items, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1.0), TimeSpan.Zero);
}
// Bind your data somewhere
```

Comment: thanks alot Mikael Svenson,, although this is not what i want..i tag C# and ASP.net to assure that this is asp.net web site but the question is so general. thanks

Comment: Added a general commet at the top as well.

Comment: @user418343 If you said a bit more about what kind of website you are creating we could be more creative in the answer. But you could also look into live twitter feeds or feeds from other relevant social media.

Comment: this is an economical site like gate to help investors in their small business

Comment: So you need economic news, maybe stock tickers, updated currency information. Check your favorite sites and see if they offer rss or other api's for this information. Live stock and currency information might only be available as paid services.